# fancybox won't popup while call it with wildcard-selector

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I have a foreach which loops my li-elements. In this elements I set the href attribute to  #Sendbox which is the id of calling div-element. But the the fancybox will not work.

If I remove id-attribute from the li-element it would work as expected but that's no solution for me because I need the id-attribute to get the other data-values inside them.

This is my code:
HTML + PHP:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($arrTags as $key => $value) { ?>
<li><a href="#SendBox" class="TheBox" id="setTag_<?php echo $value['userID']; ?>" data-tagid="<?php echo $value['tagID']; ?>"><?php echo $value['userName']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>  
<div id="SendBox" style="display:none"><h2>Box was sent..</h2></div>
```

This is my fancybox code:

```
$('[id^=setTag_]').click(function() {
$('.TheBox').click(function(){  
    $(".TheBox").fancybox({
        width   : 350,
        height  : 400,
    });
});
});
```

I have tried to find workout for but still have no luck.
Maybe anyone know the solution for that?

Comment: you're attaching a click listener inside another click listener, that seems strange. also, rendered html with maybe 2 li's would be better to show that php, to make sure there's no problem there

Comment: You're right, it was my wrong. Anyway, when removing the second listener the problem still the same, it won't load fancybox. But thank you for attention.

Comment: what version of fancybox?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic doesn't make sense because you can either call fancybox using the ID (`setTag_*`) or the class (`TheBox`) of the element, otherwise is redundant and can create unexpected results. Additionally, you don't need the `.click()` method, unless you want to call fancybox in manual mode.

Either of these scripts work :

```
$(".TheBox").fancybox({
    width: 350,
    height: 400 //<-- No trial comma on the last option
});
```

... or

```
$('[id^=setTag_]').fancybox({
    width: 350,
    height: 400 //<-- No trial comma on the last option
});
```

... **yes**, fancybox supports wild-card selectors. See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M9JHY/)**